# Bash script to find a directory, list its contents and sub-folders info

Tags: bash, path, find, directory, locate

I want to write a script that will:

1- locate folder "store" on a *nix filesystem

2- move into that folder

3- print list of contents with last modification date

4- calculate sub-folders size

This folder's absolute path changes from server to server, but the folder name remains the same always.

There is a config file that contains the correct path to that folder though, but it doesn't give absolute path to it.

Sample Config:

---

Account          ON

DIR-Store     /hdd1

Scheduled        YES

---

ِAccording to the config file the absolute path would be "/hdd1/backup/store/"

I need the script to grep the "/hdd1" or anything beyond the word "DIR-Store", add "/backup/store/" to it, move into folder "store", print list of its contents, and calculate the sub-folder's size.

Until now I manually edit the script on each server to reflect the path to the "store" folder.

Here is a sample script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo " "

echo " "

echo "Moving Into Directory"

cd /hdd1/backup/store/

echo "Listing Directory Content"             

echo " "

ls -alh

echo "*******************************"

sleep 2

echo " "

echo "Calculating Backup Size"

echo " "

du -sh store/*

echo "**********   Done!   **********"
```

I know I could use grep

```
cat /etc/store.conf | grep DIR-Store
```

I just don't know how to get around selecting the path, adding the "/backup/store/" and moving ahead.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut` to extract columns from the configuration file. Specify a field delimiter with `-d`. Cut only allows single-character delimiters (like e.g. a single space) and there are certainly gazillion other ways to split the line.

Then just manually append the know subdirectory to the stem.

```
STORE=$(grep DIR-Store /etc/store.conf | cut -d" " -f2)
DIR="${STORE}/backup/store"

pushd "${DIR}"
ls -alh
sleep 2
du -sh *
popd
```

Comment: @ honk
Your approach gave me a: 

line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'


I tired replacing the space between quotes in   ( -d" " ) with a tab, still didn't work


But Thank you!

Comment: @Lithium: fixed missing quota

Comment: @ honk

Thank you so much. now it works. Didn't notice the missing quota!

Still, I had to remove the /backup  from the line DIR="${STORE}/backup/store"

Otherwise it looks for the directory at /backup/backup/store.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If there are no spaces on that line except for the one(s) between "DIR-Store" and the directory:

```
dir=($(grep "DIR-Store" /etc/store.conf))
dir="${dir[1]}/backup/store"
cd "$dir"    # or pushd "$dir"
```

or this keys on the first slash rather than a space:

```
dir=$(grep "DIR-Store" /etc/store.conf)
dir="/${dir#*/}/backup/store"
cd "$dir"    # or pushd "$dir"
```

Comment: @ Dennis Williamson

This works!
Just had to edit the line 

dir="${dir[1]}/backup/store"

to be

dir="${dir[1]}/store"

Then it excuted just fine.

Thank you a ton!